# ExtJS How to format the input data for Save method

Tags: extjs

How to format the input data before calling the save command in ExtJS

Below is the model of group. For Adding the new group the user has an option to enter   either dn or dn_query.

If the user wants to have the dn then the REST API need to have the
following data format :

```
** {
  "id": "f4287ae0",
  "dn": "dc=example,dc=com",
  "label" : 'lable1'
  }
```

But if the user wants to enter the dn_query then the REST API need to have the following data format:

```
 ** {
      "id": "f4287ae0",
       "dn_query": {
            "domain": "dc=example",
            "query": "account=account1"
        }
      "label" : 'label'
  }
```

How to change the model so it can handle bot data formats>

```
// This is model
Ext.define('Console.model.Group', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [{
    name: 'id',
    type: 'string'
  }, {
    name : 'label',
    type : 'string',
  } , {
    name: 'dn', 
    type: 'string'
  }, {
    name: 'dn-query', 
    type: 'string', 
  }],
   proxy: {
      simpleSortMode: true,
     type: 'rest',
       url: '/api/group',
      reader:  {
          type: 'json',
          root: 'data',
          totalProperty: 'total'
      }
   }

});

var app = Console.model.Group.create(values);
var f = this;
app.save({
.....
})
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `string` from the `dn_query` field definition. This will prevent conversion to string before sending value to server, which means you can do:

```
Ext.create('Console.model.Group', {
                dn_query: {
                    "domain": "dc=example",
                    "query": "account=account1"
                },
                label: 'label2'
            });
```

Also add `convert: null` to both `dn` and `dn_query` fields. This will prevent sending values that have not been explicitly set.

Full example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/p6d

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my question – I will try to change the model and you have suggested  and test the ADD method

Comment: I have another question about the GET method. Can you take a look to see if you have solution for my problem